# How to animate textview text to resize when scrollview is scrolling

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I have text view which is outside scroll view I want when I scroll down the text view to resize text to min 15sp and when I scroll up to resize to 25sp I try with on scroll listener on scroll method to set Size on the text - 0.01f in each scroll, but It doesn't look ok I want some kind of animation only when I scroll.

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
    android:text="Some text"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cons1"
    />
```

I alos try with `setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(12,25, 2,TextView.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);`
but its seems this also does not resize the text properly or I miss something

Answer (score 0):

If there is no better way，u can try this

```
val tvSize = maxSize * scrollPercent
 //tvAnimation.textSize = tvSize
 tvAnimation.scaleX = scrollPercent
 tvAnimation.scaleY = scrollPercent
```

in addition, use `setPivotX`  to change pivot point for scaling and rotating

Comment: I need it for java project can you give me example with Java

Comment: scrollPercent is a float value which calculated based on the scroll distances，u can get it just like you calculate the text size,  the only diff is change `setTextSize()` to `setScaleX()` and `setScaleY()`

Comment: @Override
            public void onScrollChange(@Nullable NestedScrollView view, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                
                float scrollPercent =  scrollY/ view.getMeasuredHeight()*1.0f;
                
                // change pivot point
                t1.setPivotX(0);
                t1.setPivotY(0);
                
                // scale the textview
                t1.setScaleX(scrollPercent);
                t1.setScaleY(scrollPercent);
            }